# Parsing a Bash Export Variable with minidom, Error in Python

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

In my /etc/bash.bashrc file, I have following:

```
export SYNCTOOL=/root/Desktop/gb
alias synctest='python $SYNCTOOL/App.py'
```

In App.py:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
XML = parse('$SYNCTOOL/Data/Config.xml')
```

When I type "synctest" in my shell, I'm getting the error below:

```
root@bt:~# synctest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/gb/App.py", line 12, in <module>
    XML = parse('$SYNCTOOL/Data/Config.xml')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parse
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$SYNCTOOL/Data/Config.xml'
```

When I look for the file with "cat" command:

```
root@bt:~# cat $SYNCTOOL/Data/Config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AllConfigurations>

        <!-- PROGRAM OPTIONS START -->
..
...
```

So, I'm really confused. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash variable are not automatically expanded, use `os.environ` to access them:

```
XML = parse('%s/Data/Config.xml' % os.environ['SYNCTOOL'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use the value of the *shell* variable `$SYNCTOOL` in the *Python* program:

```
XML = parse('$SYNCTOOL/Data/Config.xml')
```

If you want to read environment variables from within Python programs, use the [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ) object:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ["HOME"]
/home/sarnold
>>>
```

Or, you could read the name of the file to parse from the command line arguments using [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.argv).